# iOS MapView only adding first annotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an array named allposts that has 4 objects in it.  When I run the loop below, only the first annotation is put onto the map.  I print out the latitude and longitude of each "point" and they are indeed different, so Im not sure whats going on

```
for (PFObject *post in _allPosts)
{
       NSLog(@"NEWANNOTATION");
       PFGeoPoint *point = [post objectForKey:@"Location"];
       NSLog(@"lat: %f  long: %f", point.latitude, point.longitude);
       CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude);
       CCBAnnotation *annotation = [[CCBAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];
       [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: What are the coordinates of the 4 objects?  After the `for` loop, put `NSLog(@"mapView.ann.count = %d, ", self.mapView.annotations.count);` and let us know what it says.  Are the posts very close to each other?  Maybe you need to zoom in to see them separated.  Have you implemented the viewForAnnotation method?  You don't need to implement it but if you have, please show that code.

Answer (score 0):

You should also inspect `mapView.annotations` after doing this in order to determine if it's an adding problem or a display problem.